# Calling Tooling API via Named Credential and refresh tokens

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I am using Named Credential to call Tooling API.

I'm seeing this warning on Named Credential and keep losing access to it. Keep getting Invalid Session Id error every few hours.

> "The authentication provider didn't provide a refresh token. If the
> access token expires, your org won't be able to access this named
> credential."

I tried giving Named Credential scope as "refresh_token full" but it failed to authenticate the named credential.

Connect App:
[image]

Auth Provider:
[image]

Named Credential:
[image]

Comment: Your scopes do not match. Connected app should have: Full and Perform requests on your behalf. Auth provider: `full refresh_token offline_access`

Comment: The advantages of using a Named Cred in this specific use case (SF to SF) are minimal. You can get away with a much simpler setup without compromising security/performance by using the session id (see [example](https://github.com/CompassionIntl/SalesforceSchemaAuditor/blob/master/classes/ObjectAuditor.cls#L71))

Answer (score 0):

In your scope, try adding `offline_access`.  I don't fully understand this whole space, but my understanding is that tells the system you're authenticating against to provide you with a refresh token.